# Transparent PNG over JPEG image in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, transparency, hover

I have jQuery hover function which a transparent image will animate up.
The following website http://www.okadadesign.no/vitaveritas/ shows a demo.

Please hover over a girl's image. In FF, IE8 etc, a magnifying glass which is png-24 comes up, but in IE7, nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the jquery library and function used?

Comment: This question is entirely dependent on an external link, and that link is now broken. I will try to close the question as lacking an [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set this in CSS for the class `hide`

```
left:0;
```